How to get acumatica URL

How to get this Acumatica URl in code
Currently i have use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString() But some time it is null. So it not solve my purpose to get URL.
Also some time PX.Data.Update.PXInstanceHelper.HostName is null

Request should not be null when it is referenced in the context of current thread. When you are in the context of a background thread like Acumatica PXLongOperation there is no Request associated to that thread and it is therefore expected to be null.
    public PXAction<DAC> testUrl;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test URL")]
    
    public virtual IEnumerable TestURL(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      // Request available in current thread context
      PXTrace.WriteInformation("Current Thread: " +
 HttpContext.Current?.Request?.GetWebsiteUrl());

      // Start background thread
      PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate()
      {
        // Request not available in background thread context
        PXTrace.WriteInformation("Background Thread: " + 
HttpContext.Current?.Request?.GetWebsiteUrl());
      });
  
      return adapter.Get();
    }


Hugues Beauséjour i have written the code in the RELEASE button which is already part of the LongRun Operation, hence which is why request is NULL. In this case, how can we get these details in the Release button?

You can't get it when you are in a context with no request, not possible. Obtain the value before launching the long operation at the time when it is available, cache it and use it later.
